# ListView item swiping horizontally to change contents

Tags: android, listview, swipe, tabview

I have an array which groups items like following.

Maruti Car - Suzuki Car - Mercedes Car - Fiat Car

Honda Bike - Yamaha Bike - Bajaj bike

Classic Cycle - Ajanta Cycle - Ladybird Cycle - Honda Cycle

.

.

.

X thing- Y thing - Z thing -N thing

Now,
I want to implement a listview in which the first item of each category shows up initially and on swiping the element the second comes up. The other categories still showing the first.

I tried the SwipeListView by 47deg ->https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview
 But it does this only for two levels i.e, open and close.
Is there anyway to implement Tabs inside a single item of listview.If not tabs, then some technique which supports this need.

Any suggestion would be of great help.
Thanks

Comment: I have also implement 47 degree swipe listview. i think you have to check your swipe listview action right and left. i think these action as         swipelistview.setSwipeActionLeft(SwipeListView.SWIPE_ACTION_REVEAL); //there are four swipe actions 
        swipelistview.setSwipeActionRight(SwipeListView.SWIPE_ACTION_REVEAL);

Comment: But the problems are:
1) Only 3 options would be available now.
2) The same backView would be visible in all the actions.
Isn't there a method with ActionBarSherlock-Tabs in each ListItem?

Comment: actually you can change the backview as you want becoz it gives the backview layout and frontview layout. i don't know that there is any method for actionbarSherlock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you could try implementing "FlipperView" in each item of the list (in some way)..

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put horizontal swipe viewpager in lisgtview but i failed to do that . then tried 4 direction viewpager library. hope this may help u

[a 4-directionalviewpager](http://vision-apps.blogspot.in/2013/05/4-directions-swipe-navigation.html)

Comment: This will restrict the number of swipes to three.
Doesn't android support Tabhosting in any List or GridViews?

Comment: this won't restrict no of swipes to three. u can modify it